# TCS Codevita 2015 Ruby code issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Hi I solved TCS codevita question it was working fine in my compiler (ruby 2.2) and other compilers online but it was giving **5 tests with Wrong Answer** error

[image]

My solution is

```
N = gets.chomp.to_i
arr = []
N.times do
  arr << gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
end

exp = gets.chomp.to_i
prod = 1
arr.each do |i|
  i.each do |j|
    prod *= j ** exp
  end
end
puts prod % 1000000007
```

Please tell me which cases are failing according to question..
PS: live coding competition is over

Comment: What's the question? If you don't think your program is being interpreted correctly by "TCS Codevita 2015" you need to take it up with them.

Comment: Did this got solved??